# Два блока рядом

Tags: css

У меня есть два блока рядом (вход и функции сервиса). Мне нужно их так сказать по равнять пробовал через position: absolute; (ставил на вход и двигал функции, но там кое что  меня не устраивало). Попробовал через таблицу на выходит так

```
<table><tr><td><?php include('auth.php');?></td><td><?php include('func.php');?></td></tr></table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. у вас тут таблица то для ячеек просто поставить `valign="top";` либо прописать в `css vertical-align: top;`

Answer (score 0):

По такому принципу надо позиционировать http://jsfiddle.net/M6T3K/1/

Comment: Попробовал возникла проблема как при absolute. Белый фон пропал

Comment: вот так http://jsfiddle.net/M6T3K/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
position:relative;
bottom: // и на сколько пикселей подянть блок нужно.
```

Comment: @HappyCougar - такой способ - это признак дурного тона и неправильной верстки